# Rails flatten quick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, flatten

I'm loading the configuration from a YAML file.

I have a hash that looks like this: `{:first=>{:abc=>[["one", "two", "three"]], :def => [["one", "two", "three"]]}, :second=>{:abc=>[["one", "two", "three"]]}}`

But I would like to get:

```
{:first=>{:abc=>["one", "two", "three"], :def => ["one", "two", "three"]}, :second=>{:abc=>["one", "two", "three"]}}
```

I.e flatten the end arrays. 
Structure is not going to be any "deeper" than displayed here.

One-liner code is preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
hash.each_value do |nested_hash|
  nested_hash.each_value do |array|
    array.flatten!
  end
end
```

or, in one-liner version:

```
hash.each_value { |nested_hash| nested_hash.each_value(&:flatten!) }
```